# Data format in gridview for decimal values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this column in datagrid view always having decimal value like (1.30) or 1.2 or 1.

I am trying to truncation the decimal value to 1 for example (1.30) should be 1.3.

How is possible to achieve thru Data format in grid view

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="TGValue" ShowHeader="False">
    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx) property to achieve that. You just need to give the proper string format. In your case it would be,

```
DataFormatString="{0:0.0}"
```

So your markup would be

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="TGValue" ShowHeader="False" DataFormatString="{0:0.0}" >
         <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:BoundField DataField="TGValue" ShowHeader="FALSE" DataFormatString="{0:0.0}" >
  <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: @Sachin hey buddy I did'nt refresh the page before uploading the answer that's why not able to see your answer